# search in folder that has a space in its name

Tags: bash

I have tried the examples below, but it does not return anything, but if I drop the name with the space in it, it works. How to handle foldernames with a space in it?

```
MainDir="/Users/redres/Dropbox/Computer\ Ebooks/Skimmed"

# FS=$'\n'

while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do
            printf 'File found: '"'%s'"'\n' "$file"
    done < <(find "$MainDir" -iname '*' -print0)

i=1

for i in $(find $MainDir -type f); do echo "$i"; done;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MainDir="/Users/redres/Dropbox/Computer\ Ebooks/Skimmed"
```

Either quote the space or `\`-escape it, not both. Use

```
MainDir="/Users/redres/Dropbox/Computer Ebooks/Skimmed"
```

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of the code is enough to make one weep!

However, this should work, assuming there isn't actually a backslash in the directory name before the space:

```
MainDir="/Users/redres/Dropbox/Computer Ebooks/Skimmed"

while IFS= read -d '' -r file
do
    printf "File found: '%s'\n" "$file"
done < <(find "$MainDir" -print0)
```

For example:

```
$ mkdir -p 'Double  Spaced  Directory/Holograms/Object Lesson'
$ cp /dev/null 'Double  Spaced  Directory/Holograms/Object Lesson/Obstacle Course'
$ MainDir=$PWD/"Double  Spaced  Directory"
$ while IFS= read -d '' -r file
> do
>     printf "File found: '%s'\n" "$file"
> done < <(find "$MainDir" -iname '*' -print0)
File found: '/Users/jleffler/soq/Double  Spaced  Directory'
File found: '/Users/jleffler/soq/Double  Spaced  Directory/Holograms'
File found: '/Users/jleffler/soq/Double  Spaced  Directory/Holograms/Object Lesson'
File found: '/Users/jleffler/soq/Double  Spaced  Directory/Holograms/Object Lesson/Obstacle Course'
$
```

Comment: sorry for the formatting, I just kept on try'ing all the examples. None of them mentioned anything about backslashes, because almost all of them used the dot in their examples.